# weird windows 7 update Intel Display

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, drivers, intel

I have this weird update in windows update on windows 7.

Full details from windows update:

> Intel Corporation - Display - 12/14/2017 12:00:00 AM - 10.18.14.4889
>
> Download size: 86.7 MB
>
> You may need to restart your computer for this update to take effect.
>
> Update type: Important
>
> Intel Corporation Display  driver update released in  December 2017
>
> More information: 
>   http://sysdev.microsoft.com/support/default.aspx
>
> Help and Support: 
>   http://support.microsoft.com/select/?target=hub

You can see it's "Important". I don't have "Optional" turned on.

I do have "Get updates for other Microsoft Products" aka Microsoft Update turned on, but I doubt that's relevant.

I have Device Installation settings set to "Never".

There's no KB number.

The more information link brings up a blank page and blank address bar in firefox for me. In IE it redirected to `E:\WESPortal_down\default.htm` no joke.

DuckDuckGo'ing the title brings this page: http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/ScopedViewInline.aspx?updateid=db4db1a5-4140-4d80-a63e-c0447c791353

Which provides almost no information, certainly no commentary, save this: " Driver Model: Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics 5200".

And you can't dl the update manually from that page.

The Intel Iris Pro Graphics 5200 driver download page doesnt have any drivers that match in version number or date: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81493/Intel-Iris-Pro-Graphics-5200

It appears from the net that things like this have happened before but I can't find any discussion on this particular one.

In response to comment, to further clarify what the the actual question is: WU is presenting me with an update about which there is literally NO information. I do not trust updates from WU unconditionally, because many have gone wrong in the past. A small percent, to be sure, but dozens maybe hundreds to date. So I ask myself, is this a good or a bad update? Literally the only piece of evidence suggesting that it's good is that it is suggested by WU. That's not enough. So I'm looking for some corroborating evidence that this is actually a good update, and not a hack, and not a corrupted or accidental update.

Do you have any info about what this update or somewhere I can learn about this update?

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: That is a driver update being provided by Microsoft for your system. It obviously sounds healthy/genuine. I keep receiving such updates on my Windows 10 laptop, with the option 'give other related updates' enabled.

Comment: In order to believe that this is a bad update, you would somehow have to believe that Microsoft's signing key had been compromised, and literally nobody else in the whole world noticed. For months. And anyway, i found the release notes for this update in 20 seconds from an Internet search (though as is typical of security updates, it says very little). So I don't know why you are still doubting it. NOT installing this has put your system at risk.

Comment: @Michael Hampton, care to share that link? Is the the one posted in my question? or another? The one I posted in my question looks auto-generated, meaning it would be there in all the negative scenarios. A security breach is one way to be compromised. A poorly tested driver or an update that got in by accident, is another. Is there even any indication that anyone else but me got that update? I can find none. Why is a driver in the 'Important' updates? If it's important, why is there no information online about what security vulnerability or bug it fixes? I remain suspicious.

Comment: I just searched for the version number and found numerous results from people who asking about the update, as well as various bits from Intel such as a [readme](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/27441/eng/ReadMe.txt) and [release notes](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/27441/eng/ReleaseNotes_15.36.34.4889.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

@Michael Hampton's hint googling just the version number was helpful. Obvious in hindsight.

It brought up [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haswell_(microarchitecture)) and [a laptopvideo2go post](https://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/32175-1018144889-153634-4th-and-5th-generation-haswell-and-broadwell-windows-81-windows-8-windows-7/) not to mention [the driver readme.txt file](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/27441/eng/ReadMe.txt) which all link the version reported by microsoft `10.18.14.4889` with the version used on intel's driver page `15.36.34.64.4889`. I don't know why there are two versioning systems.

But this driver is indeed listed as 2nd most recent (as of today, 7/30/2018) on the [Intel Iris Pro Graphics 5200 driver download page](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81493/Intel-Iris-Pro-Graphics-5200), released 1/16/2018 (1 month *after* the microsoft date), and explains it:

> is a security update for 4th generation Intel® platforms Windows 7* and Windows 8.1*.

and

> has several miscellaneous bug fixes and allows EDID override through the use of third-party applications.

That's not much detail, but it's at least confirmation that it's not a update that got released by mistake.

FYI the most recent driver release is [version `15.40.38.4963`, Date: 5/4/2018](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27780/Graphics-Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-40-?product=81493) and its readme file does not appear to have an alternate version number.

EDIT: I just tried to update this on an HP EliteDesk 4th generation Intel Core and it failed. I just hid it in Windows Update rather than debug.